# How do I insert an image using HTML.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, html.actionlink

how to insert image in html.actionlink - asp.net mvc?

i did it so, but it doesnt works.

```
<a href="<%= Html.ActionLink("search", "Search", new { searchText = "txtSearch" }, null); %>">
        <img alt="searchPage" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="17px"
            src="../../Stylesheets/search.PNG" title="search" />
```

Comment: I'd highly suggest using Url.Action()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are completely misusing the `ActionLink` helper. The helper actually produces the whole `<a href=".." ></a>` tag.

What you really want to use in this case (apart from your own written helper) is this:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Search", new { searchText = "txtSearch" }) %>">
    <img alt="searchPage" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="17px"
        src="../../Stylesheets/search.PNG" title="search" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

@Trimack is 100% correct w/ MVC2.  If people are searching for the MVC3 equivalent, here it is...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Search", new { searchText = "txtSearch" })">
    <img alt="searchPage" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="17px" src="../../Stylesheets/search.PNG" title="search" /> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have create a helper for this solution. So u can't include image to actionLink. But  with this helper class u can simply add anchor with image to view.

using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
    using System.Web.Routing;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Security.Policy;

```
namespace Helpers
{
    public static class ActionWithImageHelper
    {
        public static string AnchorIm(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {

            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
            var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceInnerHTML]", "replaceAction").ToHtmlString();


                builder.MergeAttribute("src", "<imagePath>");
                builder.MergeAttribute("alt", "<altText>");

                var renderedLink = link.Replace("replaceAction", "<>");
                link = renderedLink;


            return link.Replace("[replaceInnerHTML]",builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }

    }
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display multi images you can use `Html.ActionLink` property in your `View` as shown below. In this sample I use Detail/Edit/Delete images as a button under Action column.

**Note:** Type `Title`, `Controller` and `Action` name in `Html.ActionLink` according to your project. If you want to use empty title simply type " " for them.

```
....
//for using multiple Html.ActionLink in a column using Webgrid
grid.Column("Action", format: (item) =>
 new HtmlString(
       Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,               
           title = "Detail",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/detail.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink("Edit Record", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID, 
           title = "Edit",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/edit.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink("Delete Record", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,
           title = "Delete",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/delete.png')"
       }, null).ToString()
 )
)
....


<style type="text/css">
    a.icon-link {
        background-color: transparent; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer; 
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        margin-right: 8px; 
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

For full example, you might look at here: [How to use WebGrid in a cshtml view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042556/how-to-use-webgrid-in-a-cshtml-view)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @Html.ActionLink("linkname","action","controller") you can use following:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("action", "controller")'>
```

"images" is my folder for storing the images. `@Url.Content()` is to know the path. You can pass your action and the controller for that action to `@Url.Action()`. `@Url.Action()` works similar to the `@Html.ActionLink()`. Now your link will get replaced by the image.

Comment: This is the complete code <a href='@Url.Action("action", "controller")'>
<img src='@Url.Content("~/images/imageName.png")' /></a>