# How to use WebGrid in a cshtml view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I am able to use [WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) in any controller like:

`var grid = new WebGrid(emailsFetched, columnNames);`

I had to add a reference in my ASP.NET MVC project to `System.Web.Helpers` for this.

But when I try to use this web grid in **view** directly (to avoid instantiation and other settings in controller) it says: `The type or namespace 'WebGrid' cannot be found`. Ok, I tried to add a reference here too:

`@using System.Web.Helpers` but this throws another issue:

`There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'. You can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> section in the machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.`

This is pretty strange... I've seen enough example on net which are using WebGrid and don't have to declare anything in the cshtml view...

Can you please tell me how to solve this? Or why I encounter this very ugly issue?

Comment: Could you please try the approach given in my answer below and let me know if it works? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I've been able to notice that this:

`<assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </assemblies>`

has to be added in web config, under `system.web` section, withing `compilation` tags so it will look like:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to follow the steps below that had been tested before in an `ASP.NET MVC4` project without any problem.

**1)** Open `NuGet Package Manager` in `Visual Studio` and search *“microsoft-web-helper”* and install.

**2)** After installing it open `web.config` in your solution and change `connectionStringName` parameter for `DefaultMembershipProvider`, `DefaultRoleProvider` ve `DefaultSessionProvider` (if you do not, you might encounter 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.” error.

**3)** Rebuild your project and then use a smilar definition like below in your razor view.

**Note:** Change *"Title"*, *"Controller"* and *"Action"* names in `Html.ActionLinks` according to your project.

***View:***

```
@{
var grid = new System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(
    source: Model,
    columnNames: new List<string>() { "Title" },
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid",
    defaultSort: "Name",
    canPage: true,
    canSort: true,
    rowsPerPage: 5
    );
grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
}


@grid.GetHtml(
      tableStyle: "table", /*your class name for this property*/
      headerStyle: "webgrid-header",/*your class name for this property*/
      footerStyle: "webgrid-footer", /*your class name for this property*/
      rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style", /*your class name for this property*/
      alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",/*your class name...*/                                         selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",/*your class name for this property*/

      firstText: "<<",
      lastText: ">>",
      mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
      fillEmptyRows: true,

      columns: grid.Columns(
       grid.Column("ApplicantID", "No", style: "span1", canSort: true),
       grid.Column("Name", "Name", style: "span2", canSort: true),
       grid.Column("Surname", "Surname", style: "span2", canSort: true),
       grid.Column("Organization", "Org.", style: "span2", canSort: true),
       grid.Column("MeetingId", "Meeting", style: "span1", canSort: true),
        //some format usage samples:
        //grid.Column("Email", "e-mail", style: "span1", canSort: true, format: @<a href="mailto:@item.Email">@item.Email</a>),  
        //grid.Column("BirthDate", format: p=>p.BirthDate.ToShortDateString()),

//for using multiple Html.ActionLink in a column using Webgrid
grid.Column("Operations", format: (item) =>
 new HtmlString(
       Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,               
           title = "Detail",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/detail.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink("Edit Record", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID, 
           title = "Edit",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/edit.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink("Delete Record", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,
           title = "Delete",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/delete.png')"
       }, null).ToString()
 )
)
),
numericLinksCount: 5
)
```

Here are the `css` classes below used in `Razor`. If you would like to use your `css` definitions simply change style properties to that of yours (Some properties are optional as the ones in the `Razor View`).

```
<style type="text/css">    
    .webgrid-operations { /*for limiting the width of Operations 
                          menu used in the WebGrid*/
    width: 65px;
}

.webgrid-header td {
    text-align: left;
}

.webgrid-header th {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.webgrid td {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.webgrid-footer td {
    font-family: 'open_sanssemibold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: right !important;
    padding-right: 21px !important;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

    .webgrid-footer td a {
        text-align: right !important;
        padding: 0 .4em 0 .4em;
        font-size: .83em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
        background-color: #808080;
    }

        .webgrid-footer td a:hover {
            background-color: #6BBEC7;
        }

        .webgrid-footer td a.selected {
            background-color: #f00;
            color: #f00;
        }

.webgrid a {
    color: #fff;
}

.colRowButton {
    width: 70px;
    text-align: left;
}

.webgrid-row-style {
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #E8EEF4;*/
}

.webgrid-alternating-row td {
    /*background-color: #f9f9f9;*/
}

.webgrid-selected-row {
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
}    

<style type="text/css">
    a.icon-link {
        background-color: transparent; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer; 
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        margin-right: 8px; 
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .span5 {
    width:380px
    }
    .span4 {
    width:300px
    }
    .span3 {
    width:220px
    }
    .span2 {
    width:140px
    }
    .span1 {
    width:60px
    }
    </style>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue. Can't really take credit but I uninstalled earlier version and reinstalled latest version of Microsoft ASP.NET MVC4 from Nuget and things are working for me. Hope this helps someone else. Tried all the solutions, but this was the only thing that worked. [http://forums.asp.net/t/1823940.aspx?MVC4+WebGrid+problem+in+View+Razor+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1823940.aspx?MVC4%20WebGrid%20problem%20in%20View%20Razor%20)