# Create DataGridView HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list that i want to show over my webpage using `DataGridView`

```
@model List<Application.Models.Capture>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowList"; 
}
```

Found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDv_IzgQe0I) video and try to follow but cannot create an WebGgrid instance like at the video (not recognized)

Out of my view i can create WebGrid instance but from view not although i have added `@using System.Web.Helpers;`

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add a reference to the 'System.Web.Helpers'-Assembly in your project.

Right-click on the 'References'-folder -> Add reference -> .NET-Tab

Comment: Maybe the answer in this thread helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042556/how-to-use-webgrid-in-a-cshtml-view