# Is it possible to go to next and previous rows using Grid View?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to navigate between rows and get the row data if i have two buttons called Next and Previous. By Clicking on Next Button i get the next row data and highlight the row and previous row data on the Previous Button.

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 **GridView**.

Comment: check this article, it can give you a hint to achieve what you want : http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/324_Make_GridView_Row_Selectable_or_Clickable_using_jQuery_in_ASPNet.aspx

Comment: If you use MVC this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042556/how-to-use-webgrid-in-a-cshtml-view/19751732#19751732

Comment: Do you want just highlight next/previous row by changing it's background color or do you actually want post back passing selected row as argument? By 'get the next row data' do you mean you want to display it on some kind of form?

Comment: @PrzemG i want to get the data from row and i have few text boxes so each row column data will go in the textboxes. i dont just want to highlight i want to navigate like press on next button it will go to next row  and previous it will go to previous row if there is any previous row.

Answer (score 4):

```
int CurrentIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
if (CurrentIndex != GridView1.Rows.Count - 1){
  int NextRowIndex = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex + 1].RowIndex;
  GridView1.SelectedIndex = NextRowIndex;
  //get info
}
```

Try like that way

Comment: I have already checked the post from where you have copied and pasted the code but it didn't work :).

Comment: @MMK this should not be your attitude, he is trying to help you.

Comment: @Legendary +1 for your answer.

Comment: @sharique ansari its not about attitude its about crediting some one who have already answered it. or at least you can put some reference or link.

Comment: You are right but might be he forgot to add the reference

Comment: @sharique ansari http://forums.asp.net/t/1571655.aspx?Force+Grid+View+to+select+next+row+on+a+button_click+which+is+outside+the+grid+

Comment: If u gave me more of ur code examples, i try to help u more concretely

Answer (score 1):

How are you binding the data? (object datsource, sql datasource, datasource/databind, etc.) If you want the actual data that was used to bind the gridview you will need to get it from the datasource.

```
gv.Rows[row].Cells[col]
```

will give you what is displayed in the selected gridview row but that is going to include whatever your template shows and not just the data.

One solution would be to pass the primary key as a command argument of the select button in the gridview and then when you select the gridview it searches the datatable for that record and then you can display that data in textboxes, etc.

Add select btn col to gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSelect" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Month")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add to gridview:

```
OnRowCommand="gvReport_OnRowCommand"
```

Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPerson" />
```

Codebehind:
In this example "Month" is unique in my data, SessionDataTbl is a data table that i used to bind the gridview with.

```
protected void gvReport_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        //Find row data
        foreach (DataRow row in SessionDataTbl.Rows)
        {
            if (row["Month"].Equals(e.CommandArgument))
            {
                txtPerson.Text = row["Person"].ToString();
                //other text boxes, etc.
                break;
            }
        }
        //Add row color change
        Button btn = e.CommandSource as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            System.Web.UI.Control field = btn.Parent;
            if (field != null)
            {
                GridViewRow row = field.Parent as GridViewRow;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    const string backColor = "background-color";
                    //Remove any previous backcolor
                    foreach (GridViewRow rw in gvReports.Rows)
                    {
                        rw.Style.Remove(backColor);
                    }
                    row.Style.Add(backColor, "yellow");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses manual databinding but this could also be done using an objectdatasource, etc. but you would have to capture the datatable in the object datasource Selected event (can provide an example if needed)

Note: must have gridview viewstate enabled for this example

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using javascript only which is very fast as page doesn't do post back every time you change row.

Assume simple version of page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" runat="server" Text="Prev" OnClientClick="changeSelectedRow(-1)" />
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClientClick="changeSelectedRow(1)" />
<br />
<br />
Sample form with 2 boxes:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then this simple javascript will do the work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var selectedRow;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var rows = $('#' + '<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').find('tr');
        // select first row by default
        rows.get(1).style.backgroundColor = '#0000AA';
        selectedRow = 1;
        document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = rows.get(selectedRow).childNodes[0].innerText;
        document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').value = rows.get(selectedRow).childNodes[1].innerText;
    });

    function changeSelectedRow(step) {
        var rows = $('#' + '<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').find('tr');

        var newSelectedRow = selectedRow + step;

        if (newSelectedRow > 0 && newSelectedRow < rows.length) {
            rows.get(selectedRow).style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
            rows.get(newSelectedRow).style.backgroundColor = '#0000aa';
            selectedRow = newSelectedRow;

            document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value = rows.get(newSelectedRow).childNodes[0].innerText;
            document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').value = rows.get(newSelectedRow).childNodes[1].innerText;
        }

        // stop postback
        event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Above requires jquery to work. Instead of background color you can set 'className' to be your highlighet/normal row class.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this,

```
//variables used
int currentrow = 0;
int maxrow = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;

//on gridview fill
for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false; 
}
currentrow=0;
ataGridView1.Rows[0].Visible = true; 


//button next
if (currentrow < maxrow) 
{
dataGridView1.Rows[currentrow].Visible = false;
currentrow++;
dataGridView1.Rows[currentrow].Visible = true; 
retrieveData();
}

//button previous
if (currentrow > 0)
{
dataGridView1.Rows[currentrow].Visible = false;
currentrow--;
dataGridView1.Rows[currentrow].Visible = true;
retrieveData();
}

//retrieveData(); would be calling the void 
//that fills the textboxes with the dataGridView data;
```

I think something like this should work to cycle through the rows, I can't guarantee that it't all typed 100% correct since some of it was typed on SO in the textbox.